# How to write matchers for all the important test libraries?

Tags: testing, jvm, matcher, hamcrest

I'm currently extending [Degraph](https://github.com/schauder/degraph) to check for violation of dependency rules.

So far I have created matchers for [ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org/), since this is my favorite test library for the JVM. But many others prefer or have to use other libraries. So I'd like to provide matchers (or whatever is the appropriate equivalent) for those as well.

On the other hand I'm lazy so I don't want to provide a matcher for every conceivable library.

So the question is:

Is there some kind of matcher library that can be used in all (or the most / many) test libraries? Or maybe a wrapper that converts Hamcrest matchers to matchers for all the other libs?

The libraries I would like to support (in that order of importance):

- JUnit
- ScalaTest
- most popular testing library for Groovy
- most popular testing library for Clojure
- Specs2
- TestNG

Comment: Found an implicit conversion from Hamcrest to Specs2: https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/issues/114

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what you need? JUnit 4 has been using Hamcrest for a while now--just use Hamcrest's `assertThat` and whatever matchers you need. A failed matcher causes an `AssertionError` to be thrown which fails the test. I expect it works the same with other libraries.

Comment: I know, but the question is: is this matcher usable in all the other major test frameworks? Is the a matcher library that I can use that is supported by all the frameworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Every unit testing framework I've seen will fail a test that throws an exception.
2. Hamcrest's `assertThat(T value, Matcher<T> matcher)` will throw an `AssertionError` if `matcher.matches(value)` returns `false`.

Therefore, Hamcrest should work out-of-the-box with most testing frameworks. For other libraries, such as for building mock objects, you'll need to either use Hamcrest's `Matcher` objects natively or write an integration layer. One way would be to create a method to decorate any matcher, for example*,

```
ArgumentMatcher<T> decorate(final Matcher<T> matcher) {
    return new ArgumentMatcher() {
        public boolean <T> accepts(T value) {
            return matcher.matches(value);
        }
    }
}
```

* This is a contrived example using a theoretical Mocking API.

Comment: You are right. I guess one could at least write the equivalent of `myMatcher.match(value)` in all the test frameworks.